# Video with timed image overlay

Tags: javascript, html, video, dreamweaver, overlays

I was wondering if anyone could help me with HTML5 video with image overlays that are timed. I want the images to display and disappear at certain times, which will make the video pause and resume on the click of a button. I want to know the best approach to this in regards using HTML5, javascript etc.

I am using the video tag in HTML5 with Dreamweaver CS6 at the moment and I have full screen video working, with an image overlaid using the z-index, but I can't get it to display and disappear at a certain time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you have to add some event listener to your video:
[timeupdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441309.aspx) , [loadstart](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadstart.asp), ect to manage the visibility of your image in overlay

Comment: Thank you very much I will give that a go! Looks very similiar to ActionScript!